# Ionic 3 Tabs only show specific html in one tab

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic 3 tabs and I want that this `<ion-fab>` only would be seen in first tab :

HTML PAGE :

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root"></ion-tab> //first tab
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
//Show this only if first tab : 
    <ion-fab ngif="tabIndex = 0"></ion-fab>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class TabsPage {
  // this tells the tabs component which Pages
  // should be each tab's root Page
  tab1Root = Page1;
  tab2Root = Page2;
  tab3Root = Page3;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

If you want display ion-fab on `Page1` only you need to set the
`<ion-fab></ion-fab>` tag in `Page1` .html only.

Comment: thats bad, because if that ion fab does the same in all pages - why should I copy paste it to all other pages ? For example it works in 1 tab,2 tab and its child and dont work in 3,4,5 tab

Comment: yours case is to display the fab in first tab only right? then i cant understand what's wrong with my solution!?

Comment: my case is to determine that ion-fab would work where I want not by copying it